# js2-refactor from melpa: Package `emacs-24.1' is unavailable

Tags: emacs, elpa

I'm on GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.6.0), but when I try to use package (melpa) to install js2-refactor I get this odd error:

```
package-compute-transaction: Package `emacs-24.1' is unavailable
```

Any ideas what this could be about? Actually, this might be coming from a dependency of js2-refactor: js2-mode. It gives the same error.

Comment: Could it be the case that you have installed `package.el` for pre-24 Emacs versions?  If you're using the built-in version, `M-x locate-library RET package` should show a path ending with `lisp/emacs-lisp/package.elc`.  If not, getting rid of the file indicated could help.

Comment: @legoscia: That did it! I had an old version (from 2007 ver. 0.9) running in an old modes directory. Clearing it and restarting solved it. Thanks.

Comment: @legoscia your advice solved my problem as well. Could you perhaps add it as an answer so it can be accepted+get a vote?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The reason for this can be a lingering old version of `package.el` in your load path.  `package.el` was officially included in GNU Emacs 24, and the downloadable file for earlier Emacs versions doesn't support dependencies on built-in packages (`emacs-24.1` is considered a built-in package here).

Type `M-x locate-library RET package` to find where Emacs is getting its `package.el` from. The path it shows should end with `lisp/emacs-lisp/package.elc`.  If it doesn't, try getting rid of the indicated file (or changing the load path so Emacs doesn't find it).

Comment: Can then the faulty package.el be unloaded or do you have to restart Emacs ?

Comment: Not sure. Loading the right file with `M-x load-file` might be enough, but there is only one way to find out. (Perhaps the old version set a variable to a value that won't work with the new one, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar issue by uninstalling and reinstalling emacs (macOS/homewbrew).