# Using magit in gnu emacs on osx

Tags: emacs, magit

I am trying to install emacs 24 and magit, however when I try to install magit from the package list, I get the error "Package emacs-23.2 is unavailable". I'm not sure of I need to install emacs 23 too or what.

Comment: It sounds like [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16211305/113848).

Comment: I think I got the correct path for the package. It points to a file in the emacs.app

Comment: possible duplicate of [js2-refactor from melpa: Package \`emacs-24.1' is unavailable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177807/js2-refactor-from-melpa-package-emacs-24-1-is-unavailable)

Comment: I do not think I have the same problem as the linked problem. My version is actually using the built-in package manager and magit is asking for an *older* version. I have tried moving every package.el file out of the directory listed when I ran locate-library to the point where emacs gave me the message "cannot locate library". I still received the error after every removed package.el

Comment: You can always just pull the source code from the Github website and save the files to your hard drive and forget about messing around with package install.  There is a convenient link to just download the whole zipped archive:   https://github.com/magit/magit  And, of course, you can clone everything to your hard drive.  You can do the same thing with the dependencies.

Comment: That's true. If I don't get a fix, I'll probably just do that.

Comment: Why not do yourself a favor and download a brand spanking new Emacs built for OSX?:  http://emacsformacosx.com/  You can even try the latest nightly build:  http://emacsformacosx.com/builds  After you do that, you shouldn't have any problems.  Be sure to backup and then remove your prior installation.  NOTE:  some versions of OSX ship with an old version of Emacs (`/usr/bin/emacs`), so make sure you are using the current version.

Comment: Did you try `M-x package-refresh-contents`? You should update your post with the output of `M-x emacs-version`. Also, open `package.el` (you can find it by `M-x locate-library RET package`) and post the version of package.el (it's in the comments at the top), also, post the output of `C-h v RET package-archives`. This might make it easier for someone to spot the problem.

Comment: I think package-refresh-contents worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CarlGroner It's time for you to post your comment as an answer and collect the bounty... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that now, see https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1369.

(I originally deleted this answer right after creation because I considered it unnecessary because some of the comments got it basically right. But to give future readers more confidence in the validity of these responses, I am now undoing the deletion.)