# helm installation: Package emacs '24.4' unavailable

Tags: emacs, emacs24, emacs-helm

While installing helm in emacs, I have come across the error

> Package emacs '24.4' unavailable

I am a noob to emacs and I have seen [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177807/js2-refactor-from-melpa-package-emacs-24-1-is-unavailable) on stack, but the solution offered there doesn't not solve the problem.

> Type M-x locate-library RET package to find where Emacs is getting its package.el from. The path it shows should end with lisp/emacs-lisp/package.elc. If it doesn't, try getting rid of the indicated file (or changing the load path so Emacs doesn't find it).

Can somebody help?

Below is my init.el file (configuration file)

```
;; https://blog.aaronbieber.com/2015/05/24/from-vim-to-emacs-in-
fourteen-days.html 

(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" .  "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))

(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)
```

My emacs version is 24.3.1 fresh install. I have loaded the init file a few times. I am on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to install something which requires that you are running Emacs 24.4 or later.

Hence you getting the error

> Package emacs '24.4' unavailable

because

> My emacs version is 24.3.1

You'll need to upgrade to a newer version of Emacs if you want to install that package.

Comment: But I am really surprised... Helm is a very common package, used back in 2015 (according to the post). Do I always need to keep my emacs in the latest version? Which would mean, also update the plugins and make sure everything works ?

Comment: Well 24.4 is not so new -- 24.5, 25.1, and 25.2/3 were released in the interim, and 26.1 will be released in the near future -- however, if you want to use the latest version of a given *package*, it's not uncommon for package authors to limit the age of the Emacs versions that they will support (mostly likely by making use of some feature which was introduced in a particular version). You might be able to install some older version of `helm` instead, if the 24.4 requirement was not there originally (but perhaps not via the package manager).

Comment: Helm dates back to 2011, and Emacs 24.4 was released on 20/10/14, so there are indeed older versions which are compatible. Helm 2.1.0 was the last tagged release which specified Emacs 24.3. https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/tree/v2.1.0

Comment: So I should either upgrade my emacs or install older versions somehow(can you introduce me to this?)

Comment: I removed and added latest version of emacs. I don't have the error anymore. Thanks. Please check the update of your answer @ phils.

Comment: Same problem with centos 7. I solved by installing emacs from snap. https://snapcraft.io/install/emacs/centos